# How to insert items in a list between items in another list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[0,0]
```

how would I code it so that it looks something like this:

```
list1=[1,0,2,0,3]
```

I know it involves looping, and I had something like this in mind, but it's not working

```
for items in zero:
   for position in list1:
```

Comment: Look into `zip(...)` and `itertools.zip_longest(...)`.

Comment: `zipped = zip(list1, list2)` and then use 
`output = list(sum(zipped, ()))` to flatten list of tuples